# Merging 2 dicts with common elements in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
{"states":[{"status": "BV"}, {"status": "CORR"}]}
```

As is evident,it is not a simple dictionary.It is a dictionary of lists,lists which contain dictionaries.

I have another dictionary which is as follows:

```
{
"all_diseases": [
    {
        "status": "BV", 
        "median": 240.0,
        "disease_name": "Lupus"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "BV", 
        "median": 270.0,
        "disease_name": "Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "CORR", 
        "median": 480.0,
        "disease_name": "Lupus"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "CORR", 
        "median": 600.0,
        "disease_name": "Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension"
    }, 
  ]
}
```

This is also a dict of lists,lists which contain dicts. 
status key is the common element here.How can i merge these 2 structures to get an output like this:

```
{
"output": 
        [
          {
            "status":"BV",
            "data":
                    [
                      {
                        "median": 240.0,
                        "disease_name": "Lupus"
                      },
                      {
                        "median": 270.0, 
                        "disease_name": "Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension"
                      }
                    ]        
          },               
          {
            "status":"CORR",
            "data":
                    [
                      {
                        "median": 480.0,
                        "disease_name": "Lupus"
                      },
                      {
                        "median": 600.0, 
                        "disease_name": "Rheumatology"
                      }
                    ]        
           }
         ]
}
```

Comment: seems like you're just collecting objects that shares same status?

Comment: yes..exactly what i am trying to do..but getting the structure of the final output is important

Comment: how deep can the nesting get?

Comment: this is the maximum it gets to..

Comment: what has the first dict got to do with it?

Comment: now that you mention that..i can see it is redundant :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically grouping by state; you don't really need the first dictionary here:

```
states = {}
for disease in seconddict['all_diseases']:
    state = disease.pop('status')
    states.setdefault(state, []).append(disease)
```

after which you can create your output:

```
output = {'output': [
    {'status': status, 'data': diseases}
    for status, diseases in states.iteritems()]}
```

Demo:

```
>>> states = {}
>>> for disease in seconddict['all_diseases']:
...     state = disease.pop('status')
...     states.setdefault(state, []).append(disease)
... 
>>> states
{'BV': [{'disease_name': 'Lupus', 'median': 240.0}, {'disease_name': 'Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension', 'median': 270.0}], 'CORR': [{'disease_name': 'Lupus', 'median': 480.0}, {'disease_name': 'Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension', 'median': 600.0}]}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> output = {'output': [
...     {'status': status, 'data': diseases}
...     for status, diseases in states.iteritems()]}
>>> pprint(output)
{'output': [{'data': [{'disease_name': 'Lupus', 'median': 240.0},
                      {'disease_name': 'Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension',
                       'median': 270.0}],
             'status': 'BV'},
            {'data': [{'disease_name': 'Lupus', 'median': 480.0},
                      {'disease_name': 'Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension',
                       'median': 600.0}],
             'status': 'CORR'}]}
```

Comment: thanks...makes perfect sense..you have answered so many of my queries on SO..life would have been so much more difficult without your expertise..

Comment: I'd rather use `collections.defaultdict` for `states`, instead of the `setdefault` method. I personally believe it's nicer.

Comment: @Santiago: it requires an additional import, which not everyone likes. There's drawbacks and advantages to both approaches, but in the end there is no functional difference giving either an edge to solving this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is your friend here, you will need to implement the key function criteria and pass it as a parameter.

You can use like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

diseases = {
"all_diseases": [
    {
        "status": "BV", 
        "median": 240.0,
        "disease_name": "Lupus"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "BV", 
        "median": 270.0,
        "disease_name": "Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "CORR", 
        "median": 480.0,
        "disease_name": "Lupus"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "CORR", 
        "median": 600.0,
        "disease_name": "Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension"
    }, 
  ]
}

groups = groupby(diseases['all_diseases'], key=lambda item:item.get('status'))
result = []

for key_value, group_items in groups:
    result_item = {
        "status": key_value,
        "data": []
    }

    for group_item in group_items:
        del group_item["status"]
        result_item["data"].append(group_item)

    result.append(result_item)

print result
```

Comment: I don't understand why this answer got a -1, as it answers the question. As it can be seen what I did was only using a groupby, implementing a key function. The rest is creating the response.

Comment: (I didn't vote) `groupby` requires the input to be sorted. If the input isn't already sorted, that changes this from a O(N) solution (like mine) to O(NlogN).

Answer (score -1):

```
states = {"states":[{"status": "BV"}, {"status": "CORR"}]}   
status = [x.get('status') for x in states.get('states', [])]

diseases = {
"all_diseases": [
    {
        "status": "BV", 
        "median": 240.0,
        "disease_name": "Lupus"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "BV", 
        "median": 270.0,
        "disease_name": "Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "CORR", 
        "median": 480.0,
        "disease_name": "Lupus"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "CORR", 
        "median": 600.0,
        "disease_name": "Pulmonary Arterial Hypertension"
    }, 
  ]
}

print [{"status": s, "data":[{"median": x.get("median"), "disease_name": x.get("disease_name")} for x in diseases.get("all_diseases", []) if x.get("status") == s]} for s in status]
```